# where to put the comma between two distinct quote?

Tags: commas, quotes

Where should I put the comma and the quotes in such a sentence?

> The comments were significantly focused on my being “engaging, patient and extremely helpful,” “very coherent and easy-to-understand,” or "clear and straight to the point".

My question is whether I can do something like this "bla," "bla" - meaning, a simple space between two quotes and the comma before the first one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

“engaging, patient and extremely helpful”,“very coherent and easy-to-understand” or "clear and straight to the point".

You use ***commas*** to separate elements, **not** by a space.

Comment: Now this is just wrong. Where have you ever seen this?

Comment: @Reg It's right for BrE, innit?

Comment: BrE is `"", ""`, AmE is `"," ""`. There is a whitespace in both. In fact you always get a free whitespace with every comma, except in numbers.